# Some daily app statistics are currently experiencing delays. We expect to resolve the issue shortly

Tags: google-play, store, playback

I am facing issue in my play store app. Some daily app statistics are currently experiencing delays. We expect to resolve the issue shortly.

Comment: Added as an answer by accident, but I'm getting this as well. I can't see my admob performance either

Comment: Just got off chat with google support, they said they are looking into it and will email me with an update

Comment: @pedrumgolriz please update here after getting email

Comment: Still waiting on fix, this is what they sent me: "I’ve documented your issue and escalated it to our technical team for further investigation. Our team is working to resolve this issue for you as soon as possible."

Answer (score -1):

Just wait, it will be available after few days or faster. Sometimes their servers are overload and that's the reason why.